# css - per firebug - isn't working?

Tags: css, firebug

I used Firebug to inspect the HTML my php(using wordpress) files created. According to Firebug, I should utilize `#content.clearfix ul.filterable-grid clearfix li img.attachment-portfolio` to style my portfolio items, however it's not working. What am I missing?

[My site.](http://whskytngfxtrt.com/portfolio/)

Comment: A screenshot or a jsFiddle sample will increase the chance of others to be able to help you.

Comment: style how? we meed more details. What design are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use `.clearfix img.attachment-portfolio` for all your CSS needs? or you can directly use `img.attachment-portfolio`.